# Prestashop se regresa al localhost en hosting

Tags: xampp, prestashop, digitalocean

Hola instale prestashop 1.7.6 en mi pc(localhost) y todo funciono a la perfección, pero lo subí a Digital Ocean y a la hora de ingresar a la carpeta raíz de la tienda se regresa al localhost.

Ejemplo:

Ingreso a http://68.224.12.144/prestashop y automáticamente se redirecciona a http://localhost/prestashop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando dices "Subí" te refieres a que hiciste una instalación en Digital Ocean, o bien que subiste el fichero .sql y replicaste de nuevo todo?

Si es la segunda opción tendrás que reemplazar la url en la base de datos, porque por defecto tendrás puesto "localhost".

En la tabla **ps_shop_url** tendrás la columna "domain" y "domain_ssl" donde los valores deberína de ser 68.224.12.144 y no localhost.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También te sugiero que cuando trabajes en local, utilices el fichero "hosts" para emular el dominio final del proyecto. De esta forma al migrarlo al servidor, no tendrás estos problemas.

Te dejo un enlace para que puedas revisar esta opción y luego poder indagar más en ella: https://www.redeszone.net/tutoriales/internet/que-es-archivo-hosts/

Comment: Funciono gracias.